# PHP - How to get ID from URL

Tags: php, url, explode

I have 2 url -

```
$url="http://www.mysite.com/index.php?topic=23180.new#new";
$url="http://www.mysite.com/index.php/topic,23180.0.html";
```

Above both URL i am not retrieve this in the navigationbar. this is retrieve from database table and put one variable `$url`

I want to get `23180` topic id from above both url.

Now how to get this topic id?

Comment: Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I should try something using regular expressions... like:

```
/**
 * Locate and extract topic id from url received on this function.
 *
 * http://www.mysite.com/index.php?topic=23180.new#new
 * http://www.mysite.com/index.php/topic,23180.0.html
 *
 * @param string Url that must be located.
 * @return string Return that id located at string.
 * @example
 * <?php
 *     // must print 23180
 *     echo getTopicId("http://www.mysite.com/index.php?topic=23180.new#new");
 * ?>
 */
function getTopicId($urlString)
{
    return preg_replace('/topic(?:\=|\,)([0-9]+)\./i', '$1', $urlString);
}
```

Comment: Second one is coming 231800

Comment: Hi @Carlos first one is coming **http://www.mysite.com/index.php?23180new#new** Second one is **http://www.mysite.com/index.php/231800.html**

Comment: you've more then half path, study regular expressions and ask your question with base in something.

Comment: Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php instead of http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php